# How to change the color of the field in bootstrap or css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know the name of it - how can I change the color of the frame from light blue to light pink?

[image]

the class on the field are: class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid"

Comment: You mean the `border-color`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the border-color

```
.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #FFB6C1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(40, 167, 69, 0.25);
}
```

Comment: I changed it to: box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgb(245, 146, 177); because it looked green at first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `border-color:lightpink;` property to the `input` tag to achive that when it is focused like

- **Choice** : Also you can specify outline in focus if you want to let the border remain same in color on focus too but remember  you can't specify its `border-radius property`

```
input:focus{
border-color: lightpink;
border-width :2px;/*Shorthand property ~ border:2px solid lightpink*/
border-radius :3px;
}
```